# Hyperlink on portable cd

Tags: microsoft-word, compact-disc, hyperlink

I would like to burn a printable document such as microsoft word to a cd that includes other files and make a hyperlink in the document that would refer to a different file on the same cd and work when the cd is played in a differnt computer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a relative hyperlink. This should be the default behavior. The hyperlink base is the location of the current Word document.

See for more info:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/903163/how-to-create-absolute-hyperlinks-and-relative-hyperlinks-in-word-docu

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-the-hyperlink-base-address-for-relative-hyperlinks-in-a-document-83a7b7aa-a3a0-4491-8575-1b0ca207f825